# Trying to install program as non-admin user but Windows 2008 doesn't accept admin password

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008, non-admin

I am running Win 2008 Standard Ed. I am logged in as a user (non-admin) and am trying to install a program (via an install.exe file). Windows will prompt for an Admin userid and password which I do enter correctly, but it doesn't accept the credentials and keeps re-prompting for admin user and pass.

I am able to log onto the system with the admin user and password and run the executable installer. Any idea why Windows is not accepting the admin credentials?

Comment: Any differance if you Shift + RClick the installer and select "Run as Differant User", and enter the admin credentials?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I know for this, is if You are trying to install the program from a *folder* where the admin user has no access.

For example: I have a local admin account, but it has no access to the fileserver. My (non admin)user does have. I enter to the file server with my user, try to install a program, I am prompted for the admin user/pass, and it will not let me install because the admin account has no access to the file.

Only solution I know for this is to copy the files to the local drive first, than install. Or give access to the admin user.